# Specify Data Types in Redshift 'CREATE TABLE AS' Query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to specify data types and keep constraints when doing a Redshift `CREATE TABLE AS` query?

In the below example, I'd like to be able to create a copy of table1 with the column `column2` as `NVARCHAR(500)` type rather than `VARCHAR(255)` and keep the `column1` `NOT NULL` constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE test.table1 (column1 INT NOT NULL, column2 VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO test.table1
SELECT 1,'foo';

CREATE TABLE test.table2 AS
SELECT column1,CAST(column2 AS NVARCHAR(500))
FROM test.table1;
/* query executes successfully but still creates column2 as VARCHAR(255) and column1 is NULLABLE.  */

CREATE TABLE test.table2 (
    column1 INT NOT NULL
    ,column2 NVARCHAR(500)
    ) AS
SELECT column1
    ,column2
FROM test.table1;
/* ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "as" */
```

**Edit:** I'm aware that I could do this in two steps by explicitly creating `test.table2` with the correct data types and constraints, then doing an INSERT statement using the data in `test.table1`. I am curious though to see if this can be done in one CREATE TABLE AS query. Any workarounds or tips would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an SQL perspective, the answer is Yes and No.  Yes, you can specify the datatype: use `CAST` to convert the column to the type you want.  No, you can't specify constraints, because you can't: there's no syntax to do that.

If you're concerned about the constraints of a table, make it part of the schema.  If the data are determining the schema dynamically, something is amiss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple postgres casting notations with double colon,
for example,

```
create table if not exists public.test (
 my int,
 yours varchar(50)
);

insert into public.test
select 1, 'cal';
```

then use a create table as...

```
create table public.test2 as select my, yours::varchar(2000), 0::INT totty 
from public.test
;
```